# Display counts for missing dates in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

After I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT( added_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS date, 
    SUM( gender = 'male' ) AS male, 
    SUM( gender = 'female' ) AS female
FROM social_user 
WHERE social_network = 'FBuser' 
AND date( added_datetime ) BETWEEN date('2014-11-18') AND date('2014-11-20')
GROUP BY date( added_datetime )
```

I got this result:

```
date        | male | female
------------+------+--------
2014-11-19  |    2 |      0
```

But I need something different like this screenshot:

```
date        | male | female
------------+------+--------
2014-11-18  |    0 |      0
2014-11-19  |    1 |      0
2014-11-20  |    2 |      0
2014-11-21  |    0 |      0
...    
...
```

I need all date in my result set which is I used in my between operator.

Sorry for my poor English and I don't have enough reputation for attached image.

Comment: Not sure about the schema but how about `where social_network = 'FBuser' AND date( added_datetime ) BETWEEN '2014-11-18' AND '2014-11-20' GROUP BY date`

Answer (score 2):

The dates that do not exist in your data cannot magically appear in the results. One solution is to create a table of dates that contains all the dates inside a very long timespan:

```sql
CREATE TABLE datelist (DATE DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
-- dates in the past
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES ('2014-11-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES ('2014-11-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES ('2014-11-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES ('2014-11-21');
-- dates in the future
```

And use it in your JOIN query:

```sql
SELECT
    datelist.date,
    SUM(gender = 'male') AS male,
    SUM(gender = 'female') AS female
FROM datelist
LEFT JOIN social_user ON datelist.date = DATE(social_user.added_datetime)
WHERE datelist.date BETWEEN '2014-11-18' AND '2014-11-20' AND (
    social_user.id /* or whatever primary key */ IS NULL OR social_network = 'FBuser'
)
GROUP BY datelist.date
```

Sample output:

```
date                 male  female
-------------------  ----  ------
2014-11-18 00:00:00  NULL  NULL
2014-11-19 00:00:00  2     0
2014-11-20 00:00:00  1     2
```

In the above example, the two NULL columns indicates that there is no matching `social_user` record for that day. The `WHERE` clause is tweaked to include such rows.

Comment: Yes. To avoid creating `datelist` manually, the OP can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. but i think in this case year is not dynamic in "datelist" table. what if i run this query in 2015? should i add date in "datelist" table in every year? please advice..

Comment: Yes, The datelist needs to have all dates that you might need (I use 1950-01-01 ... 2050-01-01).